# Knockout JS custom scope binding

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

The Magento 2 documentation [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html#scope) states that you can use the custom Knockout JS scope binding in the standard format:

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'name.of.component'"></div>
```

But also in the format:

```
<scope args="'name.of.component'"></scope>
```

While the standard format is working fine, I'd like to use the `<scope>` format for a more 'containerless' approach, but I'm not having any joy.  Has anyone got this working?

Comment: You can do it using item in your layout handle,  <arguments>
                  <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="name.of.component" xsi:type="array">

Comment: Unfortunately `name.of.component` is dynamic so it can't be done in the layout.